Enumerating solutions of $x^2+y^2\equiv 1 \mod p^k$ with Hensel's lemma
I'd like to count the number of solutions to the equation
$$x^2 +y^2\equiv 1 \bmod p^k.$$
The case of $k=1$ is discussed here along with the number of solutions in a field of $p^k$ elements, so using an approach based on Hensel's lemma to count the arbitrary case seems viable (though I can't work out the specifics).
Running a check on a computer, it seems like the number of solutions $\mod p^k$ should be $p^{k-1}N_p$, where $N_p=p-\sin(\frac{p\pi}{2})$ is the number of solutions $\bmod p$.
For the $p^2$ case, I understand that solutions lifted via Hensel's lemma look like $(a+t_1p,b+t_1p)$, where $(a,b)$ is a solution $\bmod p$ (let's assume neither $a$ nor $b$ are $0\mod p$, there are $\frac{N_p-4}{2}$ such solutions up to symmetry). From here, if this is to be a solution $\bmod p^2$, we should have
$$a^2+b^2 +2p(at_1+bt_2)\equiv 1 \bmod p^2$$
but I don't know how to proceed.

Writing $\sin(p\pi/2)$ is excessive. When $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ that is $\sin(\pi/2) = 1$, while when $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ that is $\sin(3\pi/2) = -1$.  The more standard way to write such a $\pm 1$-valued functions is $(-1)^{(p-1)/2}$, or $(\frac{-1}{p})$ if you know Legendre symbols.

@KCd Agreed, though I was just borrowing the result from the linked reference

For each $(x,y)$ that's a solution to $x^2+y^2=1 \mod p$ we can make $p^{k-1}$ solutions modulo $p^k$. So let's see how to get them.
Without loss of generality we know that at least one of $x,y$ is nonzero, so we can call a nonzero value $x_0$ and the other value $y_0$. Then we will look at the function of $x$, $f(x)=x^2+y^2-1$ for each constant $y \in \{y_0+pz | 0 \le z < p^{k-1}\}$.
Immediately we can see that it satisfies the condition of Hensel's lemma,
$$f(x_0) = 0 \mod p$$
$$f'(x_0) = 2x_0 \ne 0 \mod p$$
Hensel's lemma also tells us this is the unique lift for $x_0$ modulo $p^k$. Each of the $N_p$ solutions has these $p^{k-1}$ lifts, giving the desired result.

What forbids solutions of the form $(x_0 +t_1p,y_0+t_2p)$ where both $t_1,t_2$ are nonzero?

Nothing forbids it. What we can't have is $x^2+y^2=1 \mod p$ with both $x=y=0 \mod p$, since $0^2+0^2 \ne 1 \mod p$. Since it's possible we have one value as $0$, such as $1^2+0^2=1$, we have to be sure to focus on the nonzero value so that we have $f'$ nonzero for our lift to work out.
